# Jenkins does not run automatically after install in Docker container

Tags: jenkins, docker

I installed Jenkins in a Docker container and it does not run automatically.
I have to run /etc/init.d/jenkins start . Then all are smooth and nice.
All the tutorials that I have followed say that after installation it should run by default , but it doesn't.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Post your docker file.

Comment: I created the container without one in order to learn Docker. As I understand it really helps others to debug my container. I'll make one for v2 of my image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like at the Dockerfile of the various Jenkins images ([like the official `_/jenkins` one](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/9395d3fdd74cd43f03b1844fbb0c3e48d713cbc1/Dockerfile)), you will see why jenkins "runs automatically":

```
COPY jenkins.sh /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]
```

(**[`tini`](https://github.com/krallin/tini)** is a script to adopt zombie processes, which is an issue I presented before in "[Use of Supervisor in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309)")

So it depends on the `ENTRYPOINT` of your Dockerfile: it should include the right command to start Jenkins.

---

> Also you can either use supervisor or entrypoint in your docker file.

No need to use supervisor: that is what tini is for in the official image.

> If I use the official jenkins image, which is configured to run jenkins automatically, I suppose I could install Locustio and start it with 'docker exec' afterwards, right?

You wouldn't install Locusto in the same image, or you wouldn't use `docker exec` to run it in the Jenkins container (`docker exec` is for opening a session mainly for debug purpose)

You would use a [Locust.io image](https://hub.docker.com/r/christianbladescb/locustio/) to run a *second* container.
If jenkins needs locust.io, you could run locust.io first, then run jenkins with [`--link` directive](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links).

Comment: Thanks VonC, I read the answer you mention, but I cannot admit that I fully understood it as I do not master Docker and it's inner works just yet. I created my container from ubuntu:latest and built it component by component. I want one container to encapsulate Jenkins for CI and Locustio (load testing) server. Should I use an official container if I understand correctly? By specifying an ENTRYPOINT dont I limit the container to run one service? Should I run the 2 services in separate containers?

Comment: That is why seeing your Dockerfile would help here

Comment: @KostasDemiris Right. The idea is to use a Dockerfile, in order to achieve a reproducible result (the same image for each docker build). See https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/

Comment: @KostasDemiris I have edited my answer to address your questions.

Comment: Ok I understand that having one application per container is the right way, right? I should rethink my architecture if this is best practice. I wanted to build a container (for each one of several developers) that would include locust and then fetch each developers code (load tests) from github , via Jenkins. Should I essentially use 2 containers for each developer? Also, I run 'docker exec -d container-name /etc/init.d/jenkins start' and worked perfectly....

Comment: @KostasDemiris using docker exec is just a way to attach oneself to a running container, it is not the right way to trigger processes. The goal is to have a `docker-compose up` which launches all the containers (here 2) with them running directly the right process. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/.

Comment: @KostasDemiris It is better to have one (or very few) process per container: that increase isolation between processes, facilitate debug per container (because one or few processes are running in said container), and ease the stop/kill process management (that I mention in http://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309)

Comment: After taking into consideration your comments I will use 2 containers (jenkins/locust) both of which will mount a common volume where jenkins will build any new code to then be used by locust.The two containers don't even need to be linked. I am too early in this project to know the rights and wrongs so I will follow the best practices

Answer (score 0):

Simple is to use official image of jenkins on docker hub. Also you can either use supervisor or entrypoint in your docker file.

Comment: If I use the official jenkins image, which is configured to run jenkins automatically, I suppose I could install Locustio and start it with 'docker exec' afterwards, right? I have no exposure to Supervisor. If it is needed I could easily pick it up if you could provide me with a nice link. Thanks

Comment: First thing first.. You can install anything in it. Run your jenkins docker with volume mountinh to /var/lib/jenkins to your host and install plugins what you want. For next time when you again create your container it will have the same settings with all plugins installed already.