# error while loadingDocker: shared libraries: libsystemd-journal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: docker, shared-libraries, libsystem

I'm using Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:25:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:25:01 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

I'm on Centos 7
I have a Jenkins-container running in my Docker Environment.
When I'm accessing the Jenkins-container and try to perform a Docker-command I got this error:

```
libsystemd-journal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried:[root@localhost lib64]# sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libsystemd.so.0 libsystemd.so.0
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘libsystemd.so.0’: File exists

I saw this issue after solving this: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34717035/how-to-run-docker-inside-jenkins-which-is-running-as-container/34717381?noredirect=1#comment57185695_34717381)

Here is the same issue: https://botbot.me/freenode/docker/2015-12-01/?page=4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After multiple comments on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34717381/6309), the [OP Jenson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558501/jenson) confirms making it work with:

> I will have to make a dockerfile because the run command is too much.
> But it works at the moment:

```
docker run -d --name jenkins --volumes-from jenkins-dv --privileged=true \
-t -i \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock 
-v $(which docker):/bin/docker \ 
-v /lib64/libsystemd-journal.so.0:/usr/lib/libsystemd-journal.so.0 \
-v /lib64/libsystemd-id128.so.0:/usr/lib/libsystemd-id128.so.0 \
-v /lib64/libdevmapper.so.1.02:/usr/lib/libdevmapper.so.1.02 \
-v /lib64/libgcrypt.so.11:/usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.11 \
-v /lib64/libdw.so.1:/usr/lib/libdw.so.1 \
-p 8080:8080 jenkins
```

I mentioned that running docker from a container ("cic": "container-in-container") means mounting the `docker` executable and `/var/run/docker.sock`.
Apparently, that particular image needs a bit more to run from within a container.

Answer (score 3):

For my developer environment, I'm runnining [docker-compose](http://www.docker.com/products/docker-compose) and I connect to the ubuntu image container (14.04 LTS) (I mount the `/var/run/docker.sock` as well).

Since an update of my host ubuntu system yesterday evening, I had the same error when I wanted to run a docker command inside the dev container :

```
[dev@docker_dev]:~$ docker ps
docker: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-journal.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I did an update and I installed `libsystemd-journal0` :

```
[dev@docker_dev]:~$ sudo apt-get update
[dev@docker_dev]:~$ sudo apt-get install libsystemd-journal0
```

And now my dev container is working fine with docker commands

Comment: with Docker 1.10 I also had to install apparmor

Comment: thank you, I just saw that I had apparmor in my docker container.

Comment: with docker 1.10, a lot has changed and there are new dependencies. their site recommends using their docker container for docker in docker. @ docker hub _/docker

Comment: actually, for my dev container I was using a phusion/baseimage (with docker 1.10.3). So I tried to do an image from scratch of ubuntu 14.04LTS. The package dependencies of docker-engine are pulling apparmor, libsystemd-journal0 and a bunch of libraries. So it works fine. Cf https://gist.github.com/bamthomas/8308226ef354a1405ad75f74a7016b13

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it appears that the shared library required by your executable is missing. One way to resolve this issue is:

1. Use "COPY" command inside Dockerfile to copy the shared libraries/dependencies inside the container. Example: COPY {local_path} {docker_path}
2. Then, set the environment variable where shared libraries are searched for first before the standard set of directories. For instance for Linux based OS, LD_LIBRARY_PATH is used. Environment variables can be set via [Docker's Environment replacement (ENV)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#environment-replacement). Example: ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH={docker_path}:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Other is to statically link your binary with the dependencies (language dependent).