# How can I "inherit" starting processes in Docker?

Tags: docker

I have a base Docker image, Base, that contains a supporting service 'helper' I want to run.  This base is not intended for direct use.

If I build another image from Base, is there a way 'helper' can be set to auto-run on start without the author of this new image being aware of having to start it.

For example I know I can doctor the CMD to start 'helper' && then do whatever the author wants.  I'm looking for a way to encapsulate starting 'helper' so the image author building on top of Base doesn't have to be aware or do anything.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using as a base image [**`phusion/baseimage-docker`**](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) ([which always starts](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/14ec533a164cdb495e1c6ab10b82ebe96695a971/image/Dockerfile#L11) the [`my_init` script](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init), to [take care of the zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309))

In that image, you [can define multiple program (daemon) to run](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding-additional-daemons):

> You only have to write a small shell script which runs your daemon, and `runit` will keep it up and running for you, restarting it when it crashes, etc.
>
> The shell script must be called `run`, must be executable, and is to be placed in the directory `/etc/service/<NAME>`.

If your base image has a `/etc/service/helper/run` script, then any image based on it would run `helper`, plus any other `/etc/service/xxx/run` script of your own.