# Dockerfile - set ENV to result of command

Tags: dockerfile, env

Is it possible to set a docker ENV variable to the result of a command?
Like:

```
ENV MY_VAR whoami
```

i want MY_VAR to get the value "root" or whatever whoami returns

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201271/parse-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command-in-dockerfile

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse a variable with the result of a command in DockerFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201271/parse-a-variable-with-the-result-of-a-command-in-dockerfile)

Answer (score 50):

As an addition to DarkSideF answer.

You should be aware that each line/command in Dockerfile is ran in another container.

You can do something like this:

```
RUN export bleah=$(hostname -f);echo $bleah;
```

This is run in a single container.

Comment: Just to clarify - `$bleah` is **not** available anywhere outside this RUN command, not even on the next line in the same dockerfile, let alone in another image it's based off. Really obvious missing feature from docker here, it does look like writing to and reading from a file is the only way to actually store (dynamic) variables in images and pass them between images, which seems super hacky.

Answer (score 35):

At this time, a command result can be used with `RUN export`, but cannot be assigned to an `ENV` variable.

Known issue: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/29110

Answer (score 26):

If you run commands using sh as it seems to be the default in docker.

You can do something like this:

```
RUN echo "export VAR=`command`" >> /envfile
RUN . /envfile; echo $VAR
....
RUN . /envfile; echo $VAR # can be re-used
```

This way, you build a env file by redirecting output to the env file of your choice. It's more explicit than having to define profiles and so on.

Then as the file will be available to other layers, it will be possible to source it and use the variables being exported. The way you create the env file isn't important.

Then when you're done you could remove the file to make it unavailable to the running container.

The `.` is how the env file is loaded.

Comment: This always comes handy!

Comment: this answer is underrated.

Comment: This results in a permissions issue, how do you fix it?

Comment: @thus__ try adding `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your `envfile`, and `["chmod", "+x", "/envfile"]` to your Dockerfile

Comment: @thus__ You probably mistyped something if you get a permission error. @JohnF's comment would help if you forgot the `.` after `RUN` but then it will fail for other reasons subsequently (i.e. the variable will not be set after the script ends).

Answer (score 25):

I had same issue and found way to set environment variable as result of function by using RUN command in dockerfile.

For example i need to set SECRET_KEY_BASE for Rails app just once without changing as would when i run:

```
docker run  -e SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(openssl rand -hex 64)"
```

Instead it i write to Dockerfile string like:

```
RUN bash -l -c 'echo export SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(openssl rand -hex 64)" >> /etc/bash.bashrc'
```

and my env variable available from root, even after bash login.
or may be

```
RUN /bin/bash -l -c 'echo export SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(openssl rand -hex 64)" > /etc/profile.d/docker_init.sh'
```

then it variable available in CMD and ENTRYPOINT commands

Docker cache it as layer and change only if you change some strings before it.

You also can try [different ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) to set environment variable.

Comment: Is /etc/profile.d/docker_init.sh still a thing?  This answer is the only mention of it that I can find with Google, and it doesn't work for me.  Was it perhaps part of a Docker execution engine in 2016 that is no longer current?

Comment: @SigmaX It's not a docker thing, it's more a **Linux** thing. Any `*.sh` file inside `/etc/profile.d/` is used to populate the environment

Answer (score 18):

This answer is a response to *@DarkSideF*,

The method he is proposing is the following, in `Dockerfile` :

```
RUN bash -l -c 'echo export SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(openssl rand -hex 64)" >> /etc/bash.bashrc'
```

( *adding an export in the `/etc/bash.bashrc`*)

It is good but the environment variable will only be available for the process `/bin/bash`, and if you try to run your docker application for example a Node.js application, `/etc/bash.bashrc` will completely be ignored and your application won't have a single clue what `SECRET_KEY_BASE` is when trying to access `process.env.SECRET_KEY_BASE`.

That is the reason why `ENV` keyword is what everyone is trying to use with a dynamic command because every time you run your container or use an `exec` command, Docker will check `ENV` and pipe every value in the process currently run (similar to `-e`).

One solution is to use a wrapper (credit to *@duglin* in this [github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110)).
Have a wrapper file (e.g. `envwrapper`) in your project root containing :

```
#!/bin/bash
export SECRET_KEY_BASE="$(openssl rand -hex 64)"
export ANOTHER_ENV "hello world"
$*
```

and then in your `Dockerfile` :

```
...
COPY . .
RUN mv envwrapper /bin/.
RUN chmod 755 /bin/envwrapper
CMD envwrapper myapp
```

Answer (score 10):

As an addition to @DarkSideF's answer, if you want to reuse the result of a previous command in your `Dockerfile` **during in the build process**, you can use the following workaround:

1. run a command, store the result in a file
2. use command substitution to get the previous result from that file into another command

For example :

```
RUN echo "bla" > ./result
RUN echo $(cat ./result)
```

For something cleaner, you can use also the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/sebpiq/02589f499c9920e70e924580a3fa9b9e/) which provides a small CLI called `envstore.py` :

```
RUN envstore.py set MY_VAR bla
RUN echo $(envstore.py get MY_VAR)
```

Or you can use [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/) library which has a similar CLI.

Comment: I am having difficulty with this interacting with `ENV`. Works with `RUN` though.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is what you were looking for, but in order to inject ENV vars or ARGS into your .Dockerfile build this pattern works.

in your my_build.sh:

```
echo getting version of osbase image to build from
OSBASE=$(grep "osbase_version" .version | sed 's/^.*: //')

echo building docker
docker build -f \
--build-arg ARTIFACT_TAG=$OSBASE \
PATH_TO_MY.Dockerfile \
-t my_artifact_home_url/bucketname:$TAG .
```

for getting an ARG in your .Dockerfile the snippet might look like this:

```
FROM scratch
ARG ARTIFACT_TAG
FROM my_artifact_home_url/bucketname:${ARTIFACT_TAG}
```

alternatively for getting an ENV in your .Dockerfile the snippet might look like this:

```
FROM someimage:latest
ARG ARTIFACT_TAG
ENV ARTIFACT_TAG=${ARTIFACT_TAG}
```

the idea is you run the shell script and that calls the .Dockerfile with the args passed in as options on the build.

Answer (score 1):

```
ARG KUBERNETES_VERSION="v1.25.2"
ENV ARCH_CMD='eval uname -m | grep -q x86_64 && echo "amd64" || echo "arm64"'
RUN curl -k -L "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$KUBERNETES_VERSION/bin/linux/$($ARCH_CMD)/kubectl" -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
    && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

basically store the command along with eval in an environment variable for later easy access but the result of the command itself is not saved as a

Answer (score 0):

From an openSUSE Leap 15 docker image, then maybe to adapt accordingly:

```
# Put variable with value in /etc/environment
RUN echo "MY_VAR=$(whoami)" >> /etc/environment
# And source /etc/environment in default .bashrc (it seems /etc/environment is not "automatically" sourced, or it is at beginning of docker build then adding afterward does not work ?)
RUN echo "source /etc/environment" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Edit: as mentioned by @tripleee this works only when subsequently running interactive Bash sessions (or you separately `source /etc/environment` when you need to).

If you want to run a specific command as `ENTRYPOINT` you can put in in a script that sources `/etc/environment` before doing anything, like for example just for `echo "MY_VAR = ${MY_VAR}"` as `ENTRYPOINT`:

Run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

source /etc/environment
echo "MY_VAR = ${MY_VAR}"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM opensuse/leap:15.0

# Only need to put variable with value in /etc/environment
RUN echo "MY_VAR=$(whoami)" >> /etc/environment

COPY Run.sh /
ENTRYPOINT [ "/Run.sh" ]
```

Comment: This only works if you subsequently run interactive Bash commands.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed, this works because my entry point is `bash`.

Comment: Well, it works in your `ENTRYPOINT` because you are explicitly sourcing `/etc/environment` in that file. My point is that this script (and most other scripts you run noninteractively) will not read `/etc/bash.bashrc` because it is only sourced by interactive shells (`bash -i`)

Comment: Yeah I understand, but since docker works as it works we need to adapt to have it almost work like original system, even if its not the best I tend to always run a script as an entry point so that I do what I want and can do things such as sourcing `/etc/environment`, doing `mount -a` when I have stuff I want to be mounted from `fstab`, other stuff that are not done like at standard boot/login since this is not how docker works. Even to have `systemctl` managing service, I fortunately found docker-systemctl-replacement that does the job, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63642719/11159476