# how to solve Docker issue Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, docker

Trying to run following command in the ubuntu 16.04 docker container

```
root@mytest:/Linux_Insight_Agent# systemctl start ir_agent.service
```

I have installed neede packages but at the time of starting the service following issue is coming.

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8):

That's because "systemctl" talks to the systemd daemon by using the d-bus. In a container there is no systemd-daemon. Asking for a start will probably not quite do what you expect - the dev-mapping need to be a bit longer.

Another solution may be to avoid the usage of a systemd daemon with the help of the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script. It overwrites default systemctl however.

Comment: To install the script just run `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/master/files/docker/systemctl.py -O /usr/local/bin/systemctl` and change the executable permissions

Answer (score 6):

I had the same situation
In my case, i resolve by running docker with `--volume` parameter.

example:

```
docker run -it \
    --volume /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro \
    --rm IMAGE /bin/bash
```

I hope works for you...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that means you're using the host docker instead of the guest docker

Answer (score 6):

https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-systemctl-failed-to-connect-to-bus-docker-ubuntu16-04-container/

The link above mentioned the follows that makes sense:

> Best Answer

I assume you start your docker container with something like

`docker run -t -i ubuntu:16.04 /bin/bash`

The problem now is that your init process PID 1 is /bin/bash, not systemd. Confirm with ps aux.

In addition to that you are missing dbus with would be the way to communicate. This is where your error message is coming from. But as your PID 1 is not systemd, it will not help to install dbus.

Best would be to re-think the way you plan to use docker. Do not rely on systemd as a process manager but have the docker container run your desired application in the foreground.

- [docker systemctl replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement)

This script may be used to overwrite "/usr/bin/systemctl".
It will execute the systemctl commands without SystemD!

Answer (score 4):

### Answer for WSL

In my case, I got this error in my WSL when running
`systemctl --user start docker-desktop` as part of the [Docker Desktop Ubuntu setup](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/install/ubuntu/)

#### Explanation

`systemctl` is an application that is dependent on `systemd`, which again provides a system and a service manager running on PID 1. **By default, this is not a part of WSL**, and the `systemctl` command above failed.

**Microsoft recently released support for `systemd` in WSL**, as announced [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/). Here they describe how you activate systemd, which I will reproduce here in a step-by-step version:

#### How to activate `systemctl` and `systemd` on WSL

1. Make sure you are running WSL version 0.67.6 or higher by running `wsl --version` in your Windows terminal *(if this fails, need to upgrade to the [Store version](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-preview-of-wsl-in-the-microsoft-store-is-now-available/#how-to-install-and-use-wsl-in-the-microsoft-store))*
2. Open WSL and navigate to your Linux **/home** directory. Navigate to **/etc**
3. Open (and if necessary, create) the **wsl.conf** file with sudo privileges, e.g. through nano: `sudo nano wsl.conf`
4. Add the following lines:

```
[boot]
systemd=true
```

5. Save and close (in nano `CTRL + 0` and `CTRL + x`)
6. Shutdown WSL in your Windows Terminal with `wsl.exe --shutdown`
7. Wait 8 seconds (see [the 8 second rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#the-8-second-rule))
8. Open WSL
9. Make sure that `systemd` and `systemctl` is working by running e.g. `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`, which should show your services’ status.

As for me, I was now able to start docker-desktop with no error.

Hopefully this can be helpful for someone else as well.