# Docker, set to env var file content

Tags: docker

How to set to `ENV` content from file? Something like this:

```
COPY file_with_content.txt ./
ENV MODEL=file_with_content.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly use a Dockerfile `ENV` to set a variable to the content of a file.

If you are directly using the `docker build` command, you can pass the file contents as a build-time argument:

```sh
ARG MODEL
ENV MODEL=$MODEL # if needed at run time
```

```sh
docker build --build-arg MODEL=$(cat file-with-content.txt) .
```

This may or may not be supported by higher-level tooling.  There's not a way to easily specify this in a `docker-compose.yml`, for example.

Otherwise, Docker has no built-in support for this, and you can use one of the techniques in [Dockerfile - set ENV to result of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command) to set the environment variable to the file contents.  For example, using an entrypoint wrapper:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export MODEL=$(cat file-with-content.txt)
exec "$@"
```

```sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"] # the script above, MUST be JSON-array syntax
CMD the main command as you had it before
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can add inside any services in docker compose yaml file, for ex -

```
services:

  application:
    image: application
    command: /start.sh
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
    - 8000:8000
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: compose/local/application/Dockerfile
```

For more you can refer from here https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/