# Docker - execute shell script to export environment variables

Tags: java, bash, docker, shell

I'm trying to export environment variables from a Docker container using a shell script. This script will run a command and save the output as an environment variable. These variables will be used by the Java application.

The shell script variables are not being populated when I run the Docker container.

What is the best way to export environment variables from a Docker container using a shell script?

```
FROM maven:3.8-amazoncorretto-11 as TEMP_BUILD_IMAGE
ENV APP_HOME=/src
WORKDIR $APP_HOME/
COPY pom.xml $APP_HOME/
RUN mvn clean
RUN mvn dependency:resolve
COPY src $APP_HOME/src/
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip
FROM amazoncorretto:11
ARG ENVIRONMENT
RUN yum install -y shadow-utils
ENV ARTIFACT_NAME=application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
WORKDIR /home/nonroot/application/
COPY environment_config.sh environment_config.sh
RUN yum install -y jq 
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
CMD ["sh", "-c", "source ./environment_config.sh && java $JAVA_OPTS -jar $ARTIFACT_NAME --spring.config.location=file:./config/application.properties"]
```

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "environment ${ENVIRONMENT}"
export API_URL=$(eval COMMAND)
```

Comment: Why do you think variables aren't getting set?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm getting null value while printing the environment variable from Java application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using script to compute environment variables in `dockerfile`.

Suggesting to look into this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command#37860420).

The question is ambiguous about `using a shell script` origin. And the target environment context.

---

#### 1. Use a shell script in the container's host.

Use `ssh` command to connect with container to dig for the required environment inside the container.

```
ssh -i container-ssh.key root@container.ip 'echo $(your-environment-var)'
```

---

#### 2. Use a shell script inside the container, to affect the environment variable of the container's host.

**No can do:** this request contradicts the fundamental container context isolation from host context.

The best suggestion is to write a shell script in the container that writes value to a file `CNT_ENV`. And file `CNT_ENV` is located in a volume accessible to container's host.

In container's host, write a script or service to update host environment variable from value in file `CNT_ENV`.

Comment: Docker entrypoint command  `source ./environment_config.sh` is not working. I can able to see the echo message but environment variable alone not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command#37860420. The official strategy is to add `./environment_config.sh` to `.profile`. Like this  `run echo ". ./environment" >> ~/.profile`

Comment: This method will not work for me. Because that script will only work after the container is started. It won't work while building the image.

Comment: Suggesting to test. Since each line in dockerfile is a container. Each line must run the login script (.profile or .bash_profile). This method should work if root shell is `sh`. If root shell is `bash` than append the `. ./environment` to `~/.bash_profile`. Or preapre a login script and copy it to the container.