# Can I use a regex or sed to create a dockerfile variable?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` that receives a `PYTHON_VERSION` ARG. I need both the full version for and the major versions only for FROM commands. Something like this:

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION  # assume 3.10.10

FROM gcr.io/something/image:${PYTHON_VERSION}
...
FROM gcr.io/something_else/image:{PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION}
```

In bash I can easily extract this with `sed -En  's/^([0-9]+[.][0-9]+).*/\1/p'` (and probably million other options). Can I do something similar in Dockerfile? Either running a regex (but the output should go to a variable), or assign the output of a RUN command to a variable?

I'm currently using two ARGs but that seems stupid...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile - set ENV to result of command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911622/dockerfile-set-env-to-result-of-command)

Comment: Unfortunately not as I need the $PYTHON_MAJOR_VERSION in the FROM command, not just as a regular env variable..