# Env variable not getting echoed in Dockerfile

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.15.1-buster

RUN npm pkg get version
RUN VERSION=$(npm pkg get version)
RUN echo "$VERSION"
```

I am using this to build the image:

```
docker build --progress plain --no-cache -t test-image-1 app/
```

This is the output:

```
#1 [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.15.1-buster@sha256:a13d2d2aec7f0dae18a52ca4d38b592e45a45cc4456ffab82e5ff10d8a53d042
#1 DONE 0.1s

#2 [ 8/12] RUN npm pkg get version
#2 1.257 "0.1.0"
#2 DONE 1.5s

#3 [ 9/12] RUN VERSION=$(npm pkg get version)
#3 DONE 0.7s

#4 [10/12] RUN echo "$VERSION"
#4 0.307 
#4 DONE 0.3s
```

Why would it not `echo` the version number in Step # 4 when it is running the same command correctly in Step # 2?

I've also tried:

```
FROM node:16.15.1-buster

RUN npm pkg get version
ENV VERSION $(npm pkg get version)
RUN echo "$VERSION"
```

but the `$VERSION` is not printed in the last step.

Comment: Because this is 2 different shell instances ?

Comment: I think the question is how to share a variable between 02 steps or shell instances. Am I ok @HelmBurger?  Did you solve your problem with the proposed answer? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68290395/3957754