# create dockerfile to build new images

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

```
FROM denmarkcontrevida/base:15.05

MAINTAINER Denmark Contrevida<denmarkcontrevida@esutek.com>

# Config files
# Config pyenv
# Config Nginx
# Config PostgreSQL
# Create DB & Restore database
```

This image will install to the newest version.

- PostgreSQL
- Nginx
- Pyenv
- Django
- Python 3

Answer (score 0):

IF are about to install that many different services, make sure to start from a base image made to manage them.

Use [**`phusion/baseimage-docker`**](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) ([which always starts](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/14ec533a164cdb495e1c6ab10b82ebe96695a971/image/Dockerfile#L11) the [`my_init` script](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init), to [take care of the zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309))

In that image, you [can define multiple program (daemon) to run](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding-additional-daemons):

> You only have to write a small shell script which runs your daemon, and `runit` will keep it up and running for you, restarting it when it crashes, etc.
>
> The shell script must be called `run`, must be executable, and is to be placed in the directory `/etc/service/<NAME>`.

If your base image has a `/etc/service/helper/run` script, then any image based on it would run `helper`, plus any other `/etc/service/xxx/run` script of your own: replace xxx by the running services like nginx, django, postgresSQL.
You wouldn't need it for python3 (which is simply called, but doesn't run in the background)

Comment: Can anyone of you send me a sample script or maybe a file that has a docker commands that will install something that has mentioned above.