# automatically start /etc/init script in IBM Bluemix container

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

I have a start-stop script in /etc/init/

With this script I can start a bash-script with: `service <script> start/stop`.

I want this script to start automatically when the container starts.
So there for I used the command `update-rc.d <script> defaults`

But when I restart the container the  won't automatically starts.

If I log in the container and I start the script with: `service <script> start` , the  starts correctly.

Also I see that there are symbolic links in /etc/rc1.d (etc) to start the init script.

How can I solve that the init script start automatically after a restart of my container.

Comment: Could you provide more info about the script in /etc/init? I suppose there is a problem with you starting script, or you are linking it in a wrong way

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [**phusion/baseimage-docker**](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) as a base image.
It is made [to declare "services"](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding-additional-daemons):

> You can add additional daemons (e.g. your own app) to the image by creating `runit` entries. You only have to write a small shell script which runs your daemon, and `runit` will keep it up and running for you, restarting it when it crashes, etc.
>
> The shell script must be called run, must be executable, and is to be placed in the directory /etc/service/.

That helps taking care of the [zombie processes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309).