# PHP / HTML form - show data on the same page in Docker container, does not print

Tags: php, html, docker, apache

I want to have an HTML/PHP simple form on Apache. I would like the user to submit some data and then this data should be shown on the same page after submission. I want to have it all in a Docker container.

It might be the Docker issue, because it works on [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

I have PHP installed on my [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) system. However, after submitting a form, I can't see the data I provided.

#### File *index.html*

```php
<?php
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ // Check if form was submitted
  $input = $_POST['inputText']; // Get input text
  $message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php echo $message; ?>
  <input type="text" name="inputText"/>
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM webdevops/php:8.2

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y apache2
RUN apt install -y apache2-utils
RUN sudo a2enmod php8.2

WORKDIR /var/www/html
EXPOSE 80

COPY index.php /var/www/html/post
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: Maybe you have some intermedia redirect that does not preserve data?

Comment: @Justinas I dont think so, because it works on localhost without any problems

Comment: Please make following: Open DevTools, in Network tab mark "reserve requests" and than submit form. Check what data is sent to back-end and what kind of requests are made. Update question with relevant information from Network tab

Comment: Are you sure this is a Docker problem? Would it work without docker? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Have you added an ```echo``` statement to print the ```$message```?

Comment: @Drk, It works without Docker

Comment: What's the PHP version on the local machine?

Comment: Using *.html* instead *.php* can't be the first time. What is the canonical duplicate question?

Answer (score 5):

Errors

1. PHP won't execute when the file name ends with `.html`. It should be `index.php`
2. You're using the PHP image of [`webdevops/php:8.2`](https://hub.docker.com/r/webdevops/php-apache-dev) which already has Apache and PHP.

   As I know, these will not work:

   ```
   RUN apt install -y apache2
   RUN apt install -y apache2-utils
   RUN sudo a2enmod php8.2
   ```
3. You're copying your file into a directory named `post` which doesn't exist and doesn't seem needed

---

Try this:

#### File *index.php*

```php
<?php
$message = "";
if(isset($_POST['SubmitButton'])){ //check if form was submitted
  $input = $_POST['inputText']; //get input text
  $message = "Success! You entered: ".$input;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php echo $message; ?>
  <input type="text" name="inputText"/>
  <input type="submit" name="SubmitButton"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache:8.2

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY index.php ./

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

Comment: `Cant connect to 127.0.0.1:7004`

Comment: what is `127.0.0.1:7004`? from where `7004` comes from ?

Comment: Why [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html)? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Possibly related: *[Alternative to supervisord for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850460/)*

Answer (score -4):

I see that in your form tag, the action attribute is empty (`action=""`). This will submit to the same URL it’s currently on.

Change it to `action="index.php"` to submit the form data to the PHP script.

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. If this worked on localhost, but no longer when using Docker, what makes you think that your hint resolves the problem? Also, what makes you think that `index.php` exists after all? The OP hasn't shared any such file

Comment: The docker file shared, says COPY index.php /var/www/html/post, so i think index.php is used

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: `index.php` will be the default page shown, so setting `action="index.php"` or leaving it blank wouldn't make any difference

Comment: Hi, Sreeram Nair.  

Most or all of your last 11 answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Many also have comments indicating that they are wrong in some respect. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.