# How to run JIRA and MySQL on same Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker, jira

I have found [this docker image with JIRA](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/) on it. JIRA can be used with MySQL, but I do not want to run MySQL on another Container.

In my opinion it is more useful to run the MySQL on the same Container (faster access, higher security, less resources, etc.).

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a base image which specializes in managing several services, in order to avoid the "[PID 1 zombie reaping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309)".

Create a dockerfile similar to the [JIRA one](https://hub.docker.com/r/cptactionhank/atlassian-jira/~/dockerfile/), but:

- with [`phusion/baseimage-docker`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) as base image
- with mysql installed ([as in this Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/ee6ac037ab647e0de9dbeb4e064610a95cb6df4a/5.7/Dockerfile))
- with both Jira and mysql declared as [additional daemons](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#adding-additional-daemons)
- with the baseimage-docker's init system:

  ```
  CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
  ```

That way, you can easily start multiple apps, and *also* stop the container while knowing *all* apps will be stopping properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did JIRA and PostgreSQL but in two containers, look at https://github.com/manufy/docker-jira-bitbucket-gitlab/blob/master/atlassian/jira/docker-compose.yml

In one container you can mix the JIRA Dockerfile and add commands to install mysql, after that only configure db on web jira install.

Perhaps will help you