# docker stop spark container from exiting

Tags: apache-spark, docker, daemon, exit, docker-compose

I know docker only listens to pid 1 and in case that pid exits (or turns into a daemon) it thinks the program exited and the container is shut down.

When apache-spark is started the `./start-master.sh` script how can I kept the container running?

I do not think: `while true; do sleep 1000;` done is an appropriate solution.

E.g. I used `command: sbin/start-master.sh` to start the master. But it keeps shutting down.

How to keep it running when started with docker-compose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Use of Supervisor in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309)", you could use [`phusion/baseimage-docker`](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker) as a base image in which you can register scripts as "services".

The [`my_init` script](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/blob/master/image/bin/my_init) included in that image will take care of the exit signals management.

And the processes launched by `start-master.sh` would still be running.
Again, that supposes you are building your `apache-spark` image starting from `phusion/baseimage-docker`.

As commented by [thaJeztah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811501/thajeztah), using an existing image works too: [`gettyimages/spark/~/dockerfile/`](https://hub.docker.com/r/gettyimages/spark/~/dockerfile/). Its default CMD will keep the container running.

Both options are cleaner than relying on a `tail -f` trick, which won't handle the kill/exit signals gracefully.

Comment: cool I will need to look a bit closer at this. Already using the phusion base image https://hub.docker.com/r/possibly/spark/

Comment: Or use an existing image; https://hub.docker.com/r/gettyimages/spark/~/dockerfile/ (or use it as an example)

Comment: @thaJeztah Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution.
Create a file `spark-env.sh` with the following contents and copy it into the spark conf directory.

```
SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE=true
```

If your CMD in the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
CMD ["/spark/sbin/start-master.sh"]
```

the container will not exit.

Comment: It looks like OP is trying to use docker-compose.  This works for me:
```    environment:
      SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE: "true"
```
Notice the quotes around "true"

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f -n 50 /path/to/spark/logfile`

This will keep the container alive and also provide useful info if you run `-it` interactive mode. You can run `-d` detached and it will stay alive.