# SSH in Docker container causes HTTP 404

Tags: php, ssh, docker, docker-compose, sshd

I have such simple `dockerfile` for PHP:

```
# Base image
FROM php:7-fpm

# Update packages list
RUN apt-get --yes update;

# Install SSH server, set root password and allow root login
RUN apt-get  --yes install openssh-server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'root:123' | chpasswd
RUN sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Run SSH server
EXPOSE 22
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

And such `docker-compose.yml` file

```
web:
  image: nginx:latest
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/nginx/log/:/var/log/nginx/
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/
  links:
    - php
    - db
  container_name: l1.web
  environment:
    - VIRTUAL_HOST=l1.app  
php:
  build: ../builds
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-php7-fpm
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/html/:/usr/share/nginx/html/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/php/config/:/usr/local/etc/php/
  working_dir: /usr/share/nginx/html/
  links:
    - db
  container_name: l1.php 
  ports:
    - "22020:22"   
db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=
     - MYSQL_USER=
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=
  expose:
     - 3306
  volumes:
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/mysql/data/:/var/lib/mysql/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/mysql/conf.d/:/etc/mysql/conf.d/
    - /c/Users/marcin/dock-test/composers/l1.app/mysql/log/:/var/log/mysql/
  ports:
    - "33060:3306"
  container_name: l1.db
```

The problem - everything is working fine until I add in my dockerfile the last shown line:

```
CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

If I add this line, SSH is working fine but I'm getting 404 when displaying the page. When I comment this line, I'm getting page without a problem but obviously this SSH is not working.

What could be the problem with this? I just want to add I need this SSH service in PHP container (and running `docker exec` in this case is not an option)

Comment: seems like a server admin question to me, not programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [base image php-fpm](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/0783dc544c4db755d177fc7eb16dfce7a53b8383/7.0/fpm/Dockerfile#L122) ends with

```
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Your own `CMD` would override that (meaning php .

One workaround would be at least to ADD and call a wrapper script which would:

- call `php-fpm`
- launch `sshd` daemon

But that wouldn't play well with stop/kill signals, which would not stop everything. [There are special images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309) for managing more than one main process.

The [OP Marcin Nabiałek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3593996/marcin-nabia%C5%82ek) confirms [in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36964652/ssh-in-docker-container-causes-http-404/36964700?noredirect=1#comment61494180_36964700):

> I've created such file:

```
#!/bin/sh 
# Start PHP 
php-fpm -D 
# Start SSH 
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

> and it seems to be working now without a problem.

Comment: Thank you for reply. This wrapper script should be simple bash script where I run those 2 commands ?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea

Comment: I've created such file: `#!/bin/sh

# Start PHP
php-fpm -D

# Start SSH
/usr/sbin/sshd -D
` and it seems to be working now without a problem. I had no clue that it's not possible to run multiple services in dockerfile

Comment: please post your comment as an answer and accept it.

Comment: @WolfgangFahl No need: this is based on my answer, and I have included Marcin's comment in said answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

A complete answer from @VonC and @Marcin Nabialek.

```sh
# php-fpm -D 
# /usr/sbin/sshd -D 

# use \n to make the content into multiple lines
RUN printf "php-fpm -D\n/usr/sbin/sshd -D" >> /start.sh

RUN chmod +x /start.sh

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```