# How can I reproduce zombie process with bash as PID1 in docker?

Tags: bash, unix, docker, zombie-process

I have a Docker container that runs bash at PID1 which in turn runs a long-running (complex) service that sometimes produces zombie processes parented to the bash at PID1. These zombies are seemingly never reaped.

I'm trying to reproduce this issue in a minimal container so that I can test mitigations, such as using a proper init as PID1 rather than bash.

However, I have been unable to reproduce the zombie processes. The bash at PID1 seems to reap children, even those it inherited from another process.

Here is what I tried:

```
docker run -d ubuntu:14.04 bash -c \
  'bash -c "start-stop-daemon --background --start --pidfile /tmp/sleep.pid --exec /bin/sleep -- 30; sleep 300"'
```

My expectation was that `start-stop-daemon` would double-fork to create a process parented to the bash at PID1, then exec into `sleep 30`, and when the sleep exits I expected the process to remain as a zombie. The `sleep 300` simulates a long-running service.

However, bash reaps the process, and I can observe that by running `strace` on the bash process (from the host machine running docker):

```
$ sudo strace -p 2051
strace: Process 2051 attached
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 9
wait4(-1,
```

I am running docker 1.11.1-rc1, though I have the same experience with docker 1.9.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.11.1-rc1, build c90c70c
$ uname -r
4.4.8-boot2docker
```

Given that strace shows bash reaping (orphaned) children, is bash a suitable PID1 in a docker container? What else might be causing the zombies I'm seeing in the more complex container? How can I reproduce?

Edit:

I managed to attach `strace` to a bash PID1 on one of the live containers exhibiting the problem.

```
Process 20381 attached
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 11185
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], 0, NULL) = 11191
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], 0, NULL) = 11203
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 11155
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 11151
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 11152
wait4(-1, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 11154
wait4(-1, [{WIFSIGNALED(s) && WTERMSIG(s) == SIGTERM}], 0, NULL) = 11332
...
```

Not sure exactly what all those exiting processes are, but none of the PIDs match those of the few defunct zombie processes that were shown by `docker exec $id ps aux | grep defunct`.

Maybe the trick is to catch it in action and see what `wait4()` returns on a process that remains a zombie...

Comment: Would the test case mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/39593409/6309 help see zombie processes?

Comment: I'm no longer working on this issue, but I believe it was resolved by upgrading the Linux kernel, suggesting the cause was a kernel bug and/or a bug in the interaction between docker and the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to verify if my jenkins container slaves can generate zombies or not.

Since my images run the `scl` binary which in turn starts the java JLNP client, I performed the following in jenkins slave groovy script console:

```
def process=new ProcessBuilder("bash", '-c', 'sleep 10 </dev/null &>/dev/null & disown').redirectErrorStream(true).start()
println process.inputStream.text
println " ps -ef".execute().text
```

Zombies have been generated. That is with `scl` ending up as PID 1.

Then I looked at your question and decided to try out bash. My first attempt was changing ENTRYPOINT to this:

```
bash -c "/usr/bin/scl enable rh-ror42 -- /usr/local/bin/run-jnlp-client $1 $2" --
```

Then looking at `ps` output I realized that PID 1 was not `bash` but in fact PID 1 was still the `scl` binary. Finally changed command to:

bash -c "/usr/bin/scl enable rh-ror42 -- /usr/local/bin/run-jnlp-client $1 $2 ; ls" --

That is adding some random second command after the `scl` command. And voila - bash became PID 1 and no zombies generate anymore.

Looking at your example, I see that you run `bash -c` with more than one command. So in your test bed, you are running something like my last command. But in your work containers, it is likely that you run `bash -c` with only one command and it appears `bash` became clever enough to effectively do an `exec`. And probably in your work containers that generate zombies, `bash` is not actually PID 1 contrary to what you expect.

Perhaps you can `ps -ef` inside your existing work containers and verify if my guess is correct.

Comment: @gzerone, hi, not sure which trick exactly you are asking about. And nothing genius, just modifying container start command and looking at `ps -ef` output to see what is **actually** running. The big surprise for me was `bash` automatic trailing `exec` which might be handy for less experienced people in some situations but is very unfortunate (read surprising) in container use cases.

Comment: hi @akostadinov, I mean how did you know adding second command (like ;ls),  so than bash became PID 1.  I searched a long time and just know bash can reap zombie process in container, but it not works for me until I see your post here. Thx.

Comment: @gzerone Well, some deduction. When I saw `bash` process replaced by the command I was executing I thought it's doing automatic `exec` call for the last command. If bash `exec`s some command it will not be able to run the following commands, thus it will not do it. So I thought, if I put another command (whatever it is) after my desired command, that would prevent this to happen.

Comment: hi @akostadinov, what about the SIGTERM unclean shutdown problem? https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/

Comment: @childno͡.de, if your app is affected by this, then I think you can do with the code provided in the blog + a `wait` call for the children. Your app would be affected if it writes to a persistent storage or you rely on the `TERM` behavior for failover when app is for example scaled down. In many cases you would **not** care though.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem while attempting to create a zombie process inside a container with `bash` as PID 1.  Turns out (as you can see from the `wait4()` calls), that `bash` actually *is* waiting on *all children* in a tight loop (`man wait` explains that waiting on `-1` will return when any child exits).

This means when an orphan is reparented to `bash`, `bash` will correctly `wait` on it to prevent it from remaining a zombie.  Very strange that all literature on the internet says otherwise.

Comment: I don’t think all the literature on the internet says bash doesn’t reap zombie children and wait() on them. :) There are still plenty of reasons that bash is not a good PID1 such as it cannot forward signals to child processes for graceful termination.

Comment: It can but it is some work: https://gist.github.com/bronger/acce7736141b3fa118b0d47f1a2035ac

Comment: @AhmetB-Google I haven't been able to find anything online saying it waits on all pids - had to `strace` to figure out what was going on.  But, yeah, it still totally shouldn't be used instead of a proper `init` (also OMGHI!SUCHAHUGEFAN!!!)

Comment: @Ahmet : While bash seems to be, at least, overkill to be a container PID1 process. Because it’s big (en so slow) for no reason. I can’t understand why it’s not a good choice. It does what it’s important : reap lasting zombies. And for signal forwarding, I can’t see what you can’t do using "trap" and "kill". Also, you often need to do some special actions from within the container at its first start, like initializing a database or a persistent volume, or exchanging an SSH key, or whatever. Having an entrypoint which is a bash script is handy for all those reasons.

Comment: But I guess the container’s way to do things is to have a complex setup of many simples containers (using Config Maps, Secrets, etc…). And not one fat container with all its logic inside an entrypoint.sh with complex signal handling…

Answer (score 0):

To test if your applications are leaving zombies, you will need to assure that `bash` is not PID 1, rather it's the first child of PID 1.

On another question [How to reap zombie process in docker container with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66438182/2816703) I had shown example how to create a container with `bash` that will ignore the zombie processes by becoming PID 1 and executing `bash` as a child. Here is `c` code that can be used to generate the container:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int status;
    status  = system("/bin/bash");
}
```

The code that generates the zombie and the dockerfile for the container can be found in the github [repository](https://github.com/jordanvrtanoski/zombie-docker-demo)

After compiling the module in an image, all you need to do is to start the container with `docker run -ti --rm image /zombie/ignore` and you will get the `bash` as a first child. To see this working in practice, check the link to the other question.

```
root@1bd66ac87f0a:/zombie# ps -eaf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 11:17 pts/0    00:00:00 /zombie/ignore
root           7       1  0 11:17 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c /bin/bash
```