# How to reap zombie process in docker container with bash

Tags: bash, docker, containers, zombie-process

Recently I'm studying [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#why-you-need-an-init-system) and if I realized correctly it's trying to:

1. runs as PID1, acting like a simple init system(reaping zombie processes)
2. signal proxy/forwarding (which bash doesn't do)

In both [here](https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/) and [here](https://github.com/krallin/tini/issues/8#issuecomment-146135930) they all mentioned that `bash` is capable of reaping zombie process so I'm trying to verify this but couldn't make it work.

First of all I wrote a simple Go program which spawn 10 zombie process:

```
func main() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)

    signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGKILL)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            sleepCmd := exec.Command("sleep", "1")
            _ = sleepCmd.Start()
        }
    }()

    fmt.Println("awaiting signal")
    sig := <-sigs
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("received %s, exiting\n", sig.String())
}
```

build a image for it:

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine3.12 as builder

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN go build -o main main.go

FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk --no-cache --update add dumb-init bash

WORKDIR /
COPY --from=builder /main /
COPY --from=builder /entrypoint.sh /
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

and if I run `docker run -d <image>` it works as expected I can see 10 zombies process in `ps`:

```
vagrant@vagrant:/vagrant/dumb-init$ ps aux | grep sleep
root      4388  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4389  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4390  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4391  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4392  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4393  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4394  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4395  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4396  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
root      4397  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    13:54   0:00 [sleep] <defunct>
```

the 2nd step is to verify `bash` is actually capable of reaping process, so I update my docker image ENTRYPOINT to entrypoint.sh, which just wrap my program with bash:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/clever
```

if I run `ps` in the container the zombie processes are still hanging there:

```
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 {entrypoint.sh} /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh
    7 root      0:00 /clever
   13 root      0:00 [sleep]
   14 root      0:00 [sleep]
   15 root      0:00 [sleep]
   16 root      0:00 [sleep]
   17 root      0:00 [sleep]
   18 root      0:00 [sleep]
   19 root      0:00 [sleep]
   20 root      0:00 [sleep]
   21 root      0:00 [sleep]
   22 root      0:00 [sleep]
   31 root      0:00 /bin/sh
   39 root      0:00 ps
```

Tried a few other way but still couldn't figure out how to reap the zombie process correctly.

thanks for the help.

Comment: What are the parent process IDs of the child processes?  In your last `ps` listing, the launching process is still running (pid 7) and I expect that to be the parent of the `sleep` processes (pid 13, 14, ...), which would mean that the `bash` root process (pid 1) won't reap them.

Comment: To have genuine zombi, the parent should not `wait` for the child and ignore the `SIGCHLD`. Once you kill the parent, the zombie processes will be moved to PID 1 as a new parent.

Comment: ahh so I have to kill pid7 process, but doing so al the children will be reaped as well (I guess this have something to do with Go GC?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote small demo in `c` that can help to demonstrate that `bash` had reaped the zombie processes and how it would look like if he had not.

First to explain the definition of zombie process. The zombie process is a process who had finished the work and generated an exit code. The resources are kept by the kernel waiting for the parent to collect the exit code.

To have zombie, parent needs to ignore the child's exit (don't issue `wait` and ignore `SIGCHLD`).

### Reaping the zombies

The following `c` code is creating two zombie processes. One belonging to the main process, and one that belongs to the first child.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Starting Program!\n");

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        pid = fork(); // Create a child zombie
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Zombie process %i of the child process\n", getpid());
            exit(10);
        } else {
            printf("Child process %i is running!\n", getpid());
            sleep(10);  // wait 10s
            printf("Child process %i is exiting!\n", getpid());
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else if (pid > 0)
    {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == 0) {
            printf("Zombie process %i from the parent process\n", getpid());
        } else {
            printf("Parent process %i...\n", getpid());
            sleep(5);
            printf("Parent process will crash with segmentation failt!\n");
            int* p = 0;
            p = 10;
        }
    }
    else perror("fork()");
    exit(-1);
}
```

I also created a docker container that will compile the file and the child. The whole project is available in following git [repository](https://github.com/jordanvrtanoski/zombie-docker-demo)

After running the build, and the demo, the following printout is shown in the console:

```
root@d2d87f4aafbc:/zombie# ./zombie & ps -eaf --forest
[1] 8
Starting Program!
Parent process 8...
Zombie process 11 from the parent process
Child process 10 is running!
Zombie process 12 of the child process
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root           8       1  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ./zombie
root          10       8  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ ./zombie
root          12      10  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00  |   \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root          11       8  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root           9       1  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -eaf --forest
root@d2d87f4aafbc:/zombie# Parent process will crash with segmentation failt!
ps -eaf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root          10       1  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ./zombie
root          12      10  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root          13       1  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -eaf --forest
[1]+  Exit 255                ./zombie
root@d2d87f4aafbc:/zombie# Child process 10 is exiting!
ps -eaf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash
root          14       1  0 10:43 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -eaf --forest
```

The main process (PID 8) creates two children.

- A child (PID 10) that will create a zombie child (PID 12) and will sleep for 10 seconds.
- A child that will become zombie (PID 11).

After the creation of the processes, the parent process will sleep for 5s and create segmentation fault, leaving the zombies.

When the main process dies, the PID 11 is inherited by `bash` and it's cleaned up (reaped). PID 10 is still working (sleeping is a kind of work for a process) he is left alone by `bash`,  since PID 11 had not invoked `wait`, the PID 12 is still zombie.

After 5 seconds, PID 11 had finished sleeping and exited. Bash had reaped and inherited PID 12 after which bash had reaped PID 12

### Leaving zombies

The other `c` application is just executing the `bash` as a child process, leaving it to be the PID 1, and he will ignore the zombies.

```
# docker run -ti --rm test /zombie/ignore
root@b9d49363cb57:/zombie# ./zombie & ps -eaf --forest
[1] 10
Starting Program!
Parent process 10...
Zombie process 13 from the parent process
Child process 12 is running!
Zombie process 14 of the child process
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 /zombie/ignore
root           7       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c /bin/bash
root           8       7  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ /bin/bash
root          10       8  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ ./zombie
root          12      10  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      |   \_ ./zombie
root          14      12  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      |   |   \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root          13      10  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      |   \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root          11       8  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ ps -eaf --forest
root@b9d49363cb57:/zombie# pParent process will crash with segmentation failt!
ps -eaf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 /zombie/ignore
root           7       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c /bin/bash
root           8       7  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ /bin/bash
root          15       8  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ ps -eaf --forest
root          12       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 ./zombie
root          14      12  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ [zombie] <defunct>
root          13       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 [zombie] <defunct>
[1]+  Exit 255                ./zombie
root@b9d49363cb57:/zombie# Child process 12 is exiting!
ps -eaf --forest
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root           1       0  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 /zombie/ignore
root           7       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 sh -c /bin/bash
root           8       7  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00  \_ /bin/bash
root          16       8  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00      \_ ps -eaf --forest
root          12       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 [zombie] <defunct>
root          13       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 [zombie] <defunct>
root          14       1  0 11:18 pts/0    00:00:00 [zombie] <defunct>
root@b9d49363cb57:/zombie#
```

So now, we have 3 zombies left in the system, hanging.