# Wondering about differences between Docker vs Supervisor

Tags: docker, supervisord, python-daemon

They seem to accomplish the same thing of managing processes. What's the difference between Docker and Supervisor?

Comment: Supervisor runs processes. Docker runs isolated containers.

Comment: I don't get it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use supervisor in a docker container actually: when you can to make sure that exiting your container will kill *all* your processes.

A Container isolate *one* main process: as long as that process runs, the container runs.

But if your container *needs* to run several processes, you need a supervisor to manage the propagation of signals, especially the one indicating a process needs to be terminated.

See more at "[Use of Supervisor in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33117068/6309)" to avoid the PID 1 zombie reaping problem. (zombie processes are processes which are never stopped, and remains "zombie", without any parent process)

Since Docker 1.12 (Q3 2016), you don't need supervisor anymore if you have multiple processes:

```
docker run --init
```

See [PR 26061](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/26061)