# DOCKER: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE - Mac

Tags: php, docker, yii, port

I'm new to Docker and just made my first steps.
I wanted to play a little bit with docker and was about configuring a Dockerfile for yii:

```
FROM php:7.2.3-apache

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git unzip zip

EXPOSE 8080

RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic test
```

Then I run the container with:

```
docker container run -d --name test -p 8080:8080 test-yii
```

When I go to `localhost:8080` i got an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.
This is the network result of `docker container inspect`:

```
"Ports": {
     "80/tcp": null,
     "8080/tcp": [
          {
               "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
               "HostPort": "8080"
          }
     ]
},
```

I appreciate every hint that helps me to solve this issue!

Edit: I forgot to mention that i connect to the container and then run `php yii serve` to test if Yii runs and this results in the above described problem.

Comment: Follow official doc https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-docker, or even my version that contains mysql and phpmyadmin support: https://github.com/FabrizioCaldarelli/yii2-docker

Comment: Can you run `curl localhost:8080 -v` and paste the output here?

Comment: @Yuankun this is the result:

`Rebuilt URL to: localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`YII` is not started when you create a container. That's because it isn't defined in `Dockerfile`. Only `apache` starts there, because that's come from the image `php:7.2.3-apache`.

The correct `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM php:7.2.3-apache

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php && \
    mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git unzip zip

EXPOSE 8080

RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic test
CMD test/yii serve 0.0.0.0
```

Now, `CMD` layer with `yii` overlaps `CMD` layer from `php:7.2.3-apache` image.

If you want to start both `yii` and `apache` inside a container you should look to [these pieces of advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090469/docker-alpine-linux-running-2-programs/).

**Update to the Edit section in the question:**

You need to run `php yii serve 0.0.0.0`. Otherwise `yii` binds to `localhost:8080` and is only accessible inside a container

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is your answer still compliant with my edit?

Comment: thank you! That solve's the problem! You really helped me out!