# Starting a Python script using rc-service

Tags: python, rc

I am trying to make `rc-service` start a Python script on startup (Alpine Linux). I have made a simplified example just to get things to work, but no luck.

I have added `local` to the `default` run-level, and I have two files in `/etc/local.d/` - both owned by `root`:

`one_api.start`:

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run
command=one_api.py
```

`one_api.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def get_root():
    return {'message':'hello, world!'}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('one_api:app', host='127.0.0.1', port=8000, log_level='info')
```

When I try to start `local` I get `* Starting local ... [!!]`. I looked for a log in `/var/log/` but `rc-service` doesn't write a log to that location, and I can't find it anywhere else. If I run the Python script manually it works fine.

Trying to start the service by itself also doesn't work:

```
$ sudo ./one_api.start start
 * Starting one_api.start ...
Segmentation fault
 * Failed to start one_api.start       [ !! ]
 * ERROR: one_api.start failed to start
```

Comment: Hi, I tired this approch for python script, but not able to figure out. I will let you know if I can do anything, mean while I used supervisord to make script run on alpine docker here is link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090469/docker-alpine-linux-running-2-programs)

Comment: @joker2368 I actually ended up using supervisord also, but I would like to avoid that.