# Which process does ` docker attach ` attaches to?

Tags: docker, docker-container

The doc says

> docker attach: Attach local standard input, output, and error streams to a running container

From my understanding, a running container can have many running processes, including those started using `docker exec`. So When using `docker attach`, which process am I attaching to exactly?

Answer (score 2):

It should attach rather to the attach terminal’s standard input, output, and error, displaying the ongoing output or to control it interactively of the `ENTRYPOINT/CMD` process.

So it does not seem to be related to a specific process.

[`docker attach`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#get-the-exit-code-of-the-containers-command) adds:

> You can attach to the same contained process multiple times simultaneously, from different sessions on the Docker host.

Still the *same* process though.

Comment: Doesn’t stdin/stdout is related to a specific process? Let’s say I have two programs running in a container, both of which can handle user input and they are writing something to stdout at the same time. When I docker attach to that container, which process my stdin/stdout relate to? i.e., which process’s output can I see and which process my input sends to?

Comment: @MarvisLu 2 programs are always by one main process associated with the container (that is why you have docker run --init) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33119321/6309. Honestly, I often start with the logs: docker logs aContainer. If those logs are done on stdout, you will see them there. No matter how many programs are running.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever process has pid 1 in the container.  If the image declared an `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile (or if you `docker run --entrypoint ...`), it's that program; if not, it's the command passed on the `docker run` command line or the Dockerfile's `CMD`.

Comment: Is there any way to attach to a specific process in the container? For example, if I docker exec a bash process but forget to add the -it flag, can I attach to the bash later? If not, the bash process would still running in the container until I manually kill it right?